# Do atheistic men have the right to cover their heads (though not faces) with hijabs in mugshots in New York city?

Tags: privacy, first-amendment, arrest, fourteenth-amendment, equal-protection

In 2020, the NYPD reached a settlement with three Muslim women who were forced to remove their hijabs (which obscured their heads, but not their faces) for the purpose of having their mugshots taken (https://ecbawm.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/ClarkSettlement.pdf)

As a result, Muslim women in New York are no longer required to remove their hijabs during mugshots.

An obvious consequence of being able to cover one's head in a mugshot is that allows one to be less identifiable (to law enforcement, to the public who may see the mugshot on the news, etc) than someone whose entire head is visible. This may be advantageous for a number of reasons.

Does the equal protection clause grant anyone in New York city - atheistic men, for example - the right to cover their head in a mugshot so long as their face is visible?

Comment: "An obvious consequence of being able to cover one's head in a mugshot is that allows one to be less identifiable " - citation needed.  It's not at all obvious to me.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, it would seem that the "citation" is the fact that NYPD required that they remove them.  There must be a valid reason, no?

Comment: @MichaelHall No doubt the NYPD _thinks_ headscarves make one less identifiable. That doesn’t mean they _actually do_, though. (That discussion might be off-topic for law.se.)

Comment: @ MartinBonnersupportsMonica I can cite my own experience of having misidentified someone based on based on a picture in which I could see only their face, and later correctly identified them when shown a picture that included the rest of their head. Some assertions do require citations, and some fall into the category of basic common sense. It is obvious that, on average, the less information you have about someone’s physical appearance, the higher your odds are of misidentifying them based on their physical appearance.

Answer (score 3):

The [order](https://casetext.com/case/clark-v-city-of-ny-14) certifying the class action and [the ruling](https://casetext.com/case/clark-v-city-of-new-york-8) provide circumstantial details that would bear on the applicability of that reasoning. The opinion frames the question as:

> Does the United States Constitution permit the New York City Police
> Department (the "NYPD") to require an observant Muslim woman to remove
> her hijab when sitting for an arrest photo? The Court holds that it
> does not.

The agreed-to settlement includes instructions to police that are broader:

> A religious head covering worn pursuant to a sincerely held religious
> belief can be retained by the prisoner while in the custody of the
> Department. However, the religious head covering must be temporarily
> removed when conducting the mandatory Department search for weapons
> and/or contraband, but will be returned to the prisoner after that
> search unless the head covering presents a risk to the safety of the
> prisoner or others.

The First-Amendment part of the ruling is that

> Clark and Aziz have no alternative means of exercising their right to
> wear a hijab in public, at all times. The Policy, although sometimes
> inconsistently applied, still requires that Clark and Aziz remove
> their hijabs and makes their photographs available to men. The Court
> agrees with Plaintiffs that permitting observant Muslim women to wear
> a hijab while being photographed as part of booking procedure would
> have reasonably accommodated their beliefs and also would be less
> burdensome on the NYPD. Indeed, snapping a Booking Photograph of an
> arrestee with her religiously compelled covering would expend fewer
> resources than “requir[ing] dialogue with arrestees and additional
> time spent negotiating removal.”

The First Amendment is equally available to males and females, and to Muslims and non-Muslims. This ruling cannot be interpreted to mean that only women or only Muslims have this right to religious expression.

The courts have also declined to engage in religion-evaluation whereby some beliefs are certified as "true religion" and others are "false religion". See [Schwarzentruber v. Gunite](https://casetext.com/case/swartzentruber-v-gunite-corp), where an employee was required to cover up his racist tattoos on the job, and sued on First Amendment accommodation grounds. The court states the relevant legal principle regarding such a suit:t

> To establish a prima facie case of religious discrimination, a
> plaintiff must show that (1) he has a sincere religious belief,
> observance or practice that conflicts with an employment requirement;
> (2) he informed his employer of the conflict; and (3) the religious
> practice was the basis for the adverse employment decision.

Plaintiff lost the case because he

> cannot show that he holds a sincere religious belief that conflicts
> with an employment requirement.

even though he alleges that

> the "Firey Cross" tattooed on his arm is one of that church's seven
> sacred symbols

The crux of the defendant's failure is that he

> does not present admissible evidence, or even contend without
> evidence, that being required to cover up his tattoo at work conflicts
> with his religious beliefs, or that he told Gunite about any conflict
> with his beliefs and Gunite's demand that he cover his tattoo. Mr.
> Swartzentruber doesn't satisfy the first and second elements of a
> prima facie case.

The atheist male hat-wearer would at a minimum have to contend that he has a deep-seated belief about the nature of the universe that he must (whatever the claim is). It is settled First Amendment law that a "religious belief" does not have to be theistic. [This page](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1318/atheism) sets forth the case law and reasoning leading to the conclusion that atheism must be treated as a religion. See [Kaufman v. McCaughtry](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-7th-circuit/1467028.html) and citations therein. That court observes that

> a religion, for purposes of the First Amendment, is distinct from a
> “way of life,” even if that way of life is inspired by philosophical
> beliefs or other secular concerns. A religion need not be based on a
> belief in the existence of a supreme being (or beings, for
> polytheistic faiths) nor must it be a mainstream faith
>
> Without venturing too far into the realm of the philosophical, we have
> suggested in the past that when a person sincerely holds beliefs
> dealing with issues of “ultimate concern” that for her occupy a “place
> parallel to that filled by ․ God in traditionally religious persons,”
> those beliefs represent her religion.  We have already indicated that
> atheism may be considered, in this specialized sense, a religion.  
> See Reed v. Great Lakes Cos. (“If we think of religion as taking a
> position on divinity, then atheism is indeed a form of religion.”).  
> Kaufman claims that his atheist beliefs play a central role in his
> life, and the defendants do not dispute that *his beliefs are deeply
> and sincerely held*.

This sketches the claims that a person would have to make in order to rely on a Free Exercise exception to a general rule.

Comment: So while the court won't decide whether a belief is a "true religious belief", it _will_ decide whether the belief (whatever it is) is sincerely held.  In other words, while an atheist man may not be able to keep their head covering while trying to make a point, an Orthodox Jewish man stands a much better chance.

Comment: Does the equal protection clause play no role in this scenario then? Some commenters above seem skeptical that the covering one’s head on average grants them the right to be slightly more difficult to identify. For those commenters, it is trivial to think of other rights one might gain by doing this - for example, the right to conceal an embarrassing case of alopecia or a neck tattoo which they regret getting, which they fear will be shown on the news. Perhaps they simply enjoy covering their head in mugshots. What are the reasons the equal protection clause not grant them this equal right?

Comment: To “simply enjoy covering your head in mugshots” isn’t a religious or atheistic religious belief.

Comment: @user6726 You wrote that a "hat-wearer would at a minimum have to contend that he has a deep-seated belief about the nature of the universe that he must (whatever the claim is)". Suppose the hat-wearer simply asserts, "I have a deep-seated belief that I am God. I feel that I must wear a hat in this picture. It follows from this that God believes that I must wear a hat in this picture". Is he then allowed to wear the hat?